# Selecting a Google Cloud Product

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage

I have an application that transcribes phone calls made to my clients using Google Speech API. Everything works well, and now I am wanting to scale my application.

I would like some sort of database that stores all of these transcriptions for each client.I would then like to make the database accessible to my clients through either SQL or another web request.However, I only want my clients to be able to access their own phone call transcriptions, and not be able to access transcriptions from my other clients' phone calls.

What Google Cloud Platform Product would be best suited to this? There seems to be many different data storage options and I am not sure which to choose from.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/) and use the client ID as a key to filter or you can have a database/schema for each client and use call IDs as keys.

> Cloud SQL is a **fully-managed database** service that makes it easy to set up, maintain, manage, and administer your relational PostgreSQL and MySQL databases in the cloud. Cloud SQL offers high performance, scalability, and convenience. Hosted on Google Cloud Platform, Cloud SQL provides a database infrastructure for applications running anywhere.

There are other choice for storage in GCP, here's a [decision tree](https://cloud.google.com/storage-options/) for choosing the right one for your use case (if I understood it right, Cloud SQL matches it)